# Turning coloured cells into no-fill cells throughout the whole excel spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

This is my code which does not seem to work. I basically get an "object required" error in the 3rd line "for each cell in UsedRange.Cells"

```
Sub AgreeAll()
  Dim myRange As Range

For Each cell In UsedRange.Cells
    If cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0) Then
        If myRange Is Nothing Then
            Set myRange = cell
        Else
            Set myRange = Union(myRange, cell)
        End If
    End If
Next

If Not myRange Is Nothing Then
    myRange.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Range("P7").ClearContents
    Columns("E:F").EntireColumn.Delete
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @ScottHoltzman here you go :)

Comment: @R3uK that is what I edited

Comment: Indeed you edited that to replace you initial code with the evolved version proposed by @MacroMan, but you didn't specify what was the problem that you have, i.e. is there an error, if yes on which line and which error... So please do this and read this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @R3uK Yes sorry for that but I am quite new on the forum. I hope I now edited it in the correct way. The error I have is on the 3rd line and it is a Run-time error "424" object required

Comment: 3rd line, do you mean `For Each` or `If` line? Did you add `Dim cell as Range`? Which version of Excel do you use?

Comment: @R3uK I mean the line "For each". I added Dim cell as Range as you suggested earlier but I still get the same error. I am using Excel 2013

Comment: The [Worksheet.UsedRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx) cannot be used that way. Click the link for the documentation.

Comment: @Zandre : Ok now you have 2 solutions! ;) Try those and let us know!

Comment: Thank you very much to all of you. I went for your last suggestion @R3uK and it worked exactly as I wished :)

Comment: Mkay, so please **take a minute to go through the tour** and learn how to accept answers and how to use votes : http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
Sub AgreeAll()
Dim wS As Worksheet, _
    myRange As Range, _
    aCell As Range

Set wS = ActiveSheet
'set ws =sheets("Your_Sheet's_Name")

With wS
    For Each aCell In .UsedRange.Cells
        If aCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0) Then
            If myRange Is Nothing Then
                Set myRange = aCell
            Else
                Set myRange = Union(myRange, aCell)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If Not myRange Is Nothing Then
        myRange.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
        .Range("P7").ClearContents
        .Columns("E:F").EntireColumn.Delete
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: what if user has other cells colored in that he wishes to keep?

Answer (score 1):

The anatomy of a basic `If` block:

```
If [condition] = [true | false] Then
    '// Do something
[Else]
    ['// Do something Else]
End If
```

---

So in your case, you would want something like:

*(Revised after comment feedback)*

```
Dim myRange As Range

For Each cell In UsedRange.Cells
    If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 44 Then
        If myRange Is Nothing Then
            Set myRange = cell
        Else
            Set myRange = Union(myRange, cell)
        End If
    End If
Next 

If Not myRange Is Nothing Then
    myRange.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    Range("P7").ClearContents
    Columns("E:F").EntireColumn.Delete
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Macro Man. How do I select the whole spreadsheet instead of range ("A1") then? I acutally would like to apply the if statement to the whole spreadsheet. Thx :)

Comment: You need to "collect" all the coloured cells in a loop - see edit above.

Comment: Would that work with Interior.Color = RGB (xxx,xxx,xxx) instead of Interior.ColorIndex = xx ? I copied pasted your lines of code (using interior.color = RGB ) into my VBA and I got an 'object required' error :/

Comment: Just a note of caution: Using `.UsedRange` could be hazardous and potentially very burdensome if there are many *unused* cells that have been embedded with various formats or other things that *cannot* be seen by the naked eye. It's always best to qualify the **real** last row / column with something like `Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlup).Row` - I point this out because in a case like this, I think it's even more important to pay attention to.

Comment: @Zandre - to use`RGB` change `.ColorIndex` to `.Color`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Absolutely agreed, but as I can't see the data to determine the last cell I've used this a "proof-of-concept" - worth the OP taking note though for sure.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman and Macro Man Thanks both for your help. I still get an 'object required' error when using .Color instead of  .ColorIndex

Comment: @Zandre - Does your statement look like this: `If cell.Interior.Color = RGB(rrr, ggg, bbb)` ... and later in the code ... `myRange.Interior.Color = RGB(rrr,ggg,bbb)`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman It does. For the rest it is exactly the same as Macro Man's suggestion

Comment: @Zandre. I just tested his code. Works great for me. Can you edit your original question with the code you have now and then we may be able to see where it may be off.

Comment: Try qualifying the usedrange with `ActiveSheet.UsedRange` - I don't know what causes it but I've had trouble with this in the past.

Answer (score 1):

It has never been determined whether the cells are orange filled by manually setting a background fill or whether they are filled by a conditional formatting rule. If the latter, then you can set the [Interior.Pattern property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835883.aspx) to white or **xlNone** all you like; the CF rule will override anything you set. You can clear the content (which I assume drives the CF rule) or delete the CF rule from that cell.

The [AutoFilter method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844%28v=office.11%29.aspx) can filter for the [Range.DisplayFormat property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838814.aspx). The .DisplayFormat includes both regular formatting and conditional formatting; i.e. if you see orange, then so does .DisplayFormat.

```
Sub AgreeAll()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim c As Long

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Worksheets("Sheet2") '<~~set this worksheet reference properly!
        'why wait until the end to do this? It only means you have to process rtwo columns you plan to delete
        .Columns("E:F").EntireColumn.Delete
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            For c = 1 To .Columns.Count
                With .Columns(c)
                    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 192, 0), _
                                Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
                    If .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
                        .Offset(1, 0).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
                        For Each rng In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                            If rng.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0) Then _
                                rng.FormatConditions.Delete
                        Next rng
                        'your code cleared P7; did you want to clear all of the orange cells?
                        '.Offset(1, 0).ClearContents
                    End If
                    .AutoFilter
                End With
            Next c
        End With
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Neither your code nor narrative adequately explains what `Range("P7").ClearContents` was supposed to do. If you wanted to clear the orange cells then I've left some commented code in the appropriate place to do that.

If you run into problems, feel free to leave a comment but remember to provide sufficient information that I can help you with it.